# Generate Automatic documentation SlimFramework

Tags: php, reflection, slim

I have a simple RESTful API that is already built using Slim Framework.

**Example of code:**

```
$app->group('/settings','authenticate','is_admin',function () use($app){
    $app->get('/gear', function () use ($app) {
        ...
    });

    $app->group('/users',function() use($app){
        $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {...});
        $app->post('/', function () use ($app) {...});
        $app->put('/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {...});
        $app->delete('/:id', function () use ($app) {...});
    });
});
```

Now, I need to build a simple page that list all my routes groups as 'resources' and nest the routes under each group so that I can add some sort of text documentation for each route group/method which I will persist later either in database or in file storage.

In summary my questions are:

1. Is there something like that already exists?
2. How can I list all routes and route groups in Slim Framework?

**My current Hack:**

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $data=[];
    //$router->routes is a protected variable, so i had to change it to public, same for $r->methods and pattern
    foreach($app->router->routes as $r){
        $x = explode('/',$r->pattern);
        $x = $x[1];
        $data[$x][$r->methods[0]][]=$r->pattern."[".implode(',',$r->middleware)."]";
    }
    print_r($data);
});
```

I gives a result like so:

```
Array
(
    [auth] => Array
        (
            [GET] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /auth/me[authenticate]
                    [1] => /auth/logout[]
                )

            [POST] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /auth/login[]
                )

            [DELETE] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /auth/logout[]
                )

        )

    [settings] => Array
        (
            [GET] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /settings/classes[authenticate,is_admin]
                    [1] => /[authenticate,is_admin]
                )

            [POST] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /settings/grades/:id/class[authenticate,is_admin]
                    [1] => /settings/grades/:id/subject[authenticate,is_admin]
                    [2] => /settings/departments/:id/grade[authenticate,is_admin]
                    [3] => /settings/subjects/:id/skills[authenticate,is_admin]
                )

        )
```

Comment: We have been using [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) for our Java based REST APIs at work. Its pretty nice. However it requires you reveal it according to its spec. That said there is a [Swagger-PHP](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/) project that lets you use standard doc blocks/annotations to do that. I would probably look in to hooking something like this, or just regular [PHPDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) (though phpdoc dosnt have any API specific tags out of the box) up.

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to do exactly this it has some limitations but it will get you part of the way there.

I used the slim middleware and created my own middleware. 
http://docs.slimframework.com/middleware/overview/

Then every time a route was used I would get the request pattern and the method. If it was a get I would use phps reflection function to get the variable types integer or string. if it was a post I would get the request body parse it and get the variable types. Then I would save these off into a json file (one file for each route) semi following the swagger-ui spec. Then I would point swagger-ui to another php script that would look at the directory with all the json files and I put it all together I to one json file that followed the swagger-ui json spec and I echo that json to swagger-ui.

This method leaves quite a bit to be desired like descriptions of everything but it got us there.. something line this.

`

```
class MyMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware
{
public $myRoute;
    public function call()
    {
                //The Slim application
                $app = $this->app;
                $this->app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', array($this, 'onBeforeDispatch'));
                //The Environment object
                $env = $app->environment;
                //The Request object
                $req = $app->request;
                $method = $req->getMethod();
                $return['operations'] = array('method'=> $req->getMethod(),"summary" =>'',"type"=>'',"nickname"=>'',"parameters"=>array());
                if($method == "POST"){
                        $parameters = json_decode($env->offsetGet('slim.input'));
                        $return['operations']['parameters'] = $parameters;
                }
                //The Response object
                $res = $app->response;
                $body = $res->getBody();
                $this->return = $return;
                //call the next middleware
                $this->next->call();
    }
         public function onBeforeDispatch()
    {
        $route = $this->app->router()->getCurrentRoute();
        $this->myRoute = $route;
         $return['path'] = $route->getPattern();
                $return = $this->return;
                if($return['operations']['method'] == "GET"){
                        $refFunc = new ReflectionFunction($route->callable);
                        foreach ($refFunc->getParameters()  as $refParameter) {
                                $return['operations']['parameters'] = array();
                                $return['operations']['parameters']['name'] = $refParameter->name;
                                $return['operations']['parameters']['required'] = $refParameter->isOptional();
                        }
                }
                echo json_encode($return);
    }
}
$app->add(new MyMiddleware);
```

` Anyways I hope it helps.